# What is the "Barry" reference about during the ice cream chase scene?

Tags: psych

In the opening of S05 E09 of *Psych*, Shawn and Gus are being chased down the pier while holding ice cream cones. Shawn throws his over the side of the pier after a second of running, but Gus doesn't, and the following exchange occurs:

> Shawn: Drop your cone!
>
> Gus: I'm not dropping my cone, Shawn!
>
> Shawn: When are you gonna eat that?!
>
> Gus: **I don't want to die on an empty stomach, Barry!**
>
> Shawn: Who is BARRY?!
>
> Gus: I DON'T KNOW!
>
> [After running a few more feet down the pier]
>
> Gus: What do we do when we get to the end of the pier?!
>
> Shawn: Why don't you ask "Barry"?!

There's a lot of irreverent, straight-up weird jokes on this show, but they're almost always rooted in a reference to something, even if it's another *Psych* moment, but I can't come up with anything.

Does anyone know what this "Barry" moment is about?

Comment: Maybe Gus wanted to give Shawn a nonsensical nickname, after being given so many himself? But he isn't as practiced at the art, so he comes up with "Barry?"

Comment: @jejorda2 valid theory, but i would argue that it was an odd situation in which to do that bit

Comment: Given that Gus immediately admits that he doesn't know who Barry is, despite being the one who brought it up, I'm thinking it's probably just a name he pulled out of his...  If Gus were making a reference to something, that would've been the cue to explain it, at least a little.